# Error while connecting exchange server from WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, ssl-certificate, iis-8, wcf-security

I am using exchange listener inside wcf service.
Recently we moved the applications to new Server.
we have installed SSL certificate as well in IIS.

we are getting error in ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(string emailAddress) method in new server.
in old server it is working fine.

In the event viewer we are able to see the below error.

**An SSL 3.0 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The TLS connection request has failed.**

Answer (score 0):

The TLS encryption protocol is not enabled on Windows Server. This may cause the connection failure of applications that connect via HTTPS protocol and TLS encryption.

You can determine which protocols are enabled by viewing the following registry keys:

[image]

To enable SSL3.0, please follow the steps below:

Using regedit to add the following keys:

1.Right click on protocols -> new -> key -> "SSL 3.0" then "TLS 1.0"

2.Under each of the keys above you need to create additional keys "Client" and "Server"

3.create DWORD (32bit) value called "Enabled" under each "Client" and "Server" key for "SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0"

DWORD (32bit) Value

Value name = Enabled

Value date = 0

Value date can be set to "1" - Enabled or "0" – Disabled

4、restart your computer to implement the change